# Unable to Configure Spring Security With X.509 Certificate and Anonymous User

Tags: spring-security

I am attempting to authenticate via X.509 smart card to my application. For the moment, my application doesn't have any users defined, so I'm trying to use anonymous authentication. I'll switch it to hasRole() once I create users.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserService" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- TODO: Enable this once I am ready to start annotating the service interfaces -->
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" /> 

<security:http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" access-denied-page="/index2.xhtml" >
    <security:anonymous enabled="true" />
    <security:x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="myUserService" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAnonymous()" requires-channel="https" />
    <!-- TODO: configure invalid-session-url, delete sessionid -->
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="2" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>

<bean id="roleVoter"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>

<bean id="roleHierarchy"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_AUTHENTICATED
            ROLE_AUTHENTICATED > ROLE_UNAUTHENTICATED
            ROLE_UNAUTHENTICATED > ROLE_ANONYMOUS
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It seems to be caught in the infinite loop issue, which I thought I was avoiding using isAnonymous().

I'm probably making a dumb error, so if someone can point out said stupidity, I'd be grateful.

Comment: just a guess: try changing requires-channel="https" to requires-channel="any"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a problem with configuring FacesServlet in web.xml. The FacesServlet was mapped to one path, which seemed to be incompatible with the intercept-url defined for Spring Security.

We've since jettisoned JSF (and good riddance).